# prove that $\quad n = E\left[ {\frac{{n - 1}}{2}} \right] + E\left[ {\frac{{n + 2}}{4}} \right] + E\left[ {\frac{{n + 4}}{4}} \right]$

Tags: real-analysis

good evening
I want to show that:
$\forall n \in \mathbb {Z}\quad :\quad n = E\left[ {\frac{{n - 1}}{2}} \right] + E\left[ {\frac{{n + 2}}{4}} \right] + E\left[ {\frac{{n + 4}}{4}} \right]$

$\begin{array}{l}
 m = E\left[ {\frac{{n - 1}}{2}} \right] + E\left[ {\frac{{n + 2}}{4}} \right] + E\left[ {\frac{{n + 4}}{4}} \right] \\ 
 \forall k \in \mathbb {Z}:E\left[ {\frac{k}{2}} \right] + E\left[ {\frac{k}{2}} \right] = k \\ 
 E\left[ {\frac{{n - 1}}{4}} \right] + E\left[ {\frac{{n - 1}}{4}} \right] \le E\left[ {\frac{{n - 1}}{2}} \right] \\ 
  \Rightarrow 2E\left[ {\frac{{n - 1}}{4}} \right] + E\left[ {\frac{{n + 2}}{4}} \right] + E\left[ {\frac{{n + 4}}{4}} \right] \le m \\ 
  \Rightarrow 4\left( {\frac{{n - 1}}{4}} \right) \le m \\ 
  \Rightarrow n - 1 \le m.....\left( 1 \right) \\ 
 m = E\left[ {\frac{{2\left( {n - 1} \right)}}{4}} \right] + E\left[ {\frac{{n + 2}}{4}} \right] + E\left[ {\frac{{n + 2}}{4} + \frac{1}{2}} \right] \\ 
 E\left[ {\frac{{n + 4}}{4}} \right] = \left\{ \begin{array}{l}
 E\left[ {\frac{{n + 2}}{4}} \right] \\ 
 E\left[ {\frac{{n + 2}}{4}} \right] + 1 \\ 
 \end{array} \right. \\ 
 m = E\left[ {\frac{{2\left( {n - 1} \right)}}{4}} \right] + E\left[ {\frac{{n + 2}}{4}} \right] + E\left[ {\frac{{n + 4}}{4}} \right] \\ 
  \Rightarrow m = \left\{ \begin{array}{l}
 E\left[ {\frac{{2\left( {n - 1} \right)}}{4}} \right] + 2E\left[ {\frac{{n + 2}}{4}} \right] \\ 
 E\left[ {\frac{{2\left( {n - 1} \right)}}{4}} \right] + 2E\left[ {\frac{{n + 2}}{4}} \right] + 1 \\ 
 \end{array} \right. \\ 
  \Rightarrow m < \left\{ \begin{array}{l}
 \frac{{2\left( {n - 1} \right)}}{4} + 2\frac{{n + 2}}{4} + 1 = n + 1 \\ 
 \frac{{2\left( {n - 1} \right)}}{4} + 2\frac{{n + 2}}{4} + 2 = n + 2 \\ 
 \end{array} \right. \\ 
  \Rightarrow m < n + 1...\left( 2 \right) \\ 
 \end{array}$

$
\begin{array}{l}
 E\left[ x \right] \\ 
 x \le E\left[ x \right] < x + 1 \\ 
 \end{array}
$

disigne integral part
How can we exclude the case $n-1$
thank you in advance

Comment: Please, what do you mean by $E\left[\cdot\right]$?

Answer (score 2):

First, the function you are denoting E[.] is more usually called the "floor" function these days, and is abbreviated as $\lfloor x \rfloor$ in latex.

The trick here is to consider the four cases n $\equiv$ 0,1,2,3 (mod 4) separately.  For example, if $n \equiv$ 0 (mod 4) then $\lfloor (n-1)/2 \rfloor = n/2 - 1$.  Similarly
$\lfloor (n+2)/4 \rfloor = n/4$ in this case and $\lfloor (n+4)/4 \rfloor = n/4 + 1$.  Adding these gives the result for the case n $\equiv$ 0 (mod 4).  Now do the same for the other cases.

Answer (score 0):

disigne integr part
$\begin{array}{l}
 E\left[ x \right] \\ 
 x \le E\left[ x \right] < x + 1 \\ 
 \end{array}$

$
\left\{ \begin{array}{l}
 n \equiv 1\left[ 4 \right] \\ 
 n \equiv 2\left[ 4 \right] \\ 
 \end{array} \right. \Rightarrow \left\{ \begin{array}{l}
 E\left[ {\frac{{n - 1}}{2}} \right] = \frac{n}{2} - 1 \\ 
 E\left[ {\frac{{n + 2}}{4}} \right] = \frac{n}{4} \\ 
 E\left[ {\frac{{n + 4}}{4}} \right] = \frac{n}{4} + 1 \\ 
 \end{array} \right. \Rightarrow E\left[ {\frac{{n - 1}}{2}} \right] + E\left[ {\frac{{n + 2}}{4}} \right] + E\left[ {\frac{{n + 4}}{4}} \right] = n
$

Answer (score 0):

$\left\{ \begin{array}{l}
 n \equiv 1\left[ 4 \right] \\ 
 n \equiv 2\left[ 4 \right] \\ 
 \end{array} \right. \Rightarrow \left\{ \begin{array}{l}
 E\left[ {\frac{{n - 1}}{2}} \right] = \frac{n}{2} - 1 \\ 
 E\left[ {\frac{{n + 2}}{4}} \right] = \frac{n}{4} \\ 
 E\left[ {\frac{{n + 4}}{4}} \right] = \frac{n}{4} + 1 \\ 
 \end{array} \right. \Rightarrow E\left[ {\frac{{n - 1}}{2}} \right] + E\left[ {\frac{{n + 2}}{4}} \right] + E\left[ {\frac{{n + 4}}{4}} \right] = n$